# Ученики и парты) запутался с кодом

Tags: javascript

программа должна принимать два числа, первое из которых кол-во учеников в классе, а второе кол-во парт. Программа должна проверить всем ли ученикам будет где сесть. Предполагается что за партой могут сидеть только 2 человека.

```
var a;
var b;
var c;
a = parseFloat(window.prompt('Введите количество учеников'));
b = parseFloat(window.prompt('Введите количество парт'));
if (b >= a) {
c = b - a;
window.alert(String(c) + String('Парт лишних'));
} else {
c = a - b;
window.alert(String(c) + String('Парт не хватает'));
}
```

Comment: "за партой могут сидеть 2 человека" - где?

Comment: @Igor, за школьным столом

Comment: Если в классе три парты, cколько там посадочных мест? А если `b` парт?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Вместо `parseFloat` используйте `parseInt`, у Вас же ученик и парта это целое число.
2. `window.alert`, `window` можно не писать, это и так глобальный обьект у браузере, т.е. функции `alert, prompt` будут доступны и без этого идентификатора.
3. `String('...')` можно не писать. Если будет число и строка, то в итоге при сложении серавно будет строка.

Что означает `tables * pupilsPerTable >= pupils`?

- `tables * pupilsPerTable` - означает все возможные места (с учетом кол-ва парт)
- И собственно, если всех возможных мест больше, чем надо мест, то **есть лишние парты**.

```js
const pupilsPerTable = 2;
const pupils = parseInt(prompt('Введите количество учеников'));
const tables = parseInt(prompt('Введите количество парт'));

if (tables * pupilsPerTable >= pupils) {
  alert(Math.floor(tables - pupils / pupilsPerTable) + ' лишних парт');
} else {
  alert(Math.ceil(pupils / pupilsPerTable - tables) + ' парты не хватает');
}
```